# PLSQL: Get number of records updated vs inserted when a merge statement is used

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Merge will always give you the number of records merged regardless of how my records inserted or updated using SQL%ROWCOUNT.

But how to find out number of records that were actually inserted vs number of records that were actually updated.

I tried options from this post but this doesn't seem to work -

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:122741200346595110

Any help?

Comment: What "options" are you referring to?  Tom Kyte states pretty unequivocally in that thread that there is, in general, no way to differentiate the number of rows inserted, updated, and deleted by a single `MERGE` statement, you can just find out the number of rows that were merged.  There are some suggestions of ways to potentially differentiate inserted from updated rows but those are rather brittle and will behave differently for different query plans.

Comment: I was referring - https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:122741200346595110#125700900346637534

Comment: OK.  As Tom points out, that approach is very fragile and depends on a particular plan.  There is no generally correct way to split out the number of rows inserted, updated, and deleted by a merge statement-- you can only determine the number of rows that were merged.  If you need separate figures, you'll probably need separate `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot, in general, differentiate how a row affected by a `MERGE` statement was affected in order to get separate counts for inserted, updated, and deleted rows.

If you really need separate figures, you could issue separate `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements though that is likely to be less efficient.  There are non-general solutions that depend on particular query plans but those are going to be rather brittle and generally wouldn't be recommended.