# SSIS Execute SQL Task, Rows affected on MERGE Statement (Oracle & SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, ssis

I have an SSIS package where I need to execute a MERGE statement with an Execute SQL Task. I need to do this both on an Oracle DB and a SQL Server 2012 DB. My question is, how can I get the number of rows affected as a ResultSet so I can save it on a variable in the SSIS package? I don't need to know if updated or inserted, and I don't want to create a procedure on Oracle because the MERGE is dynamic and calculated in the package through expressions in variables. I just want to get the value of the rows affected back.

P.S.: If I can't use the Execute SQL Task, can i at lease use a Script to run the MERGE? The problem is, from what I read, that ExecuteNonQuery() on Oracle does not return the rows affected with a MERGE. And I couldn't find any information for SQL Server. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I just checked a script with ExecuteNonQuery() for SQL Server, and it did return the number or rows affected. It would however be better if I could avoid the script and use the Execute SQL Task, but how do I get the rows affected as a ResultSet?

Comment: You can definitely do it with a Script task.   Don't know about Oracle, but look into using ExecuteScalar().

Comment: Wouldn't ExecuteScalar() only work if a table is returned and retrieves the first row of the first column? The number of rows affected is not returned in a table, is it?

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server you can use the OUTPUT clause with the merge statement. Here's something for you to read up. 
And for Oracle, read this:  [PLSQL: Get number of records updated vs inserted when a merge statement is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761485/plsql-get-number-of-records-updated-vs-inserted-when-a-merge-statement-is-used)

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/implementing-the-output-clause-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to get the SQL%ROWCOUNT as a ResultSet, since it needs to be a table, and SELECT FROM DUAL doesn't work, so I'm not sure how I can retrieve that value.

Comment: Put your merge statement in a stored proc that does a SELECT of the rowcount after the MERGE.   Call the stored proc from the execute SQL task.